# Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 10.17.0 (linux, x64)

Tags: node-oracledb

I'm updating my aws lambda functions to new node runtime 10.x from 8.11. 
For this, I updated the existing oracle binaries (node-oracledb 1.13.1) to (node-oracledb 4.1.0) and published a package in to npm registry. After updating the node-oracledb@4.1.0, I'm getting the following error when one of the lambda function tries to insert data in to oracle db.

```
> "errorType": "Error",
>     "errorMessage": "NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 10.17.0 (linux, x64)\nCannot load
> /var/task/node_modules/polaris-oracledbtest-4-lambda/build/Release/oracledb.node\nThe
> module
> '/var/task/node_modules/polaris-oracledbtest-4-lambda/build/Release/oracledb.node'\nwas
> compiled against a different Node.js version
> using\nNODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js
> requires\nNODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or
> re-installing\nthe module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm
> install`).\nNode-oracledb installation instructions:
> https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html\nYou must have
> 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with
> ldconfig.\nIf you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then
> install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
> \nhttp://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html\n",
>     "stack": [
>         "Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 10.17.0 (linux, x64)",
>         "Cannot load /var/task/node_modules/polaris-oracledbtest-4-lambda/build/Release/oracledb.node",
>         "The module '/var/task/node_modules/polaris-oracledbtest-4-lambda/build/Release/oracledb.node'",
>         "was compiled against a different Node.js version using",
>         "NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires",
>         "NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing",
>         "the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).",
>         "Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html",
>         "You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.",
>         "If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from ",
>         "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html",
>         "",
>         "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/polaris-oracledbtest-4-lambda/lib/oracledb.js:68:13)",
>         "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
>         "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
>         "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
>         "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
>         "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
>         "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
>         "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
>         "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/polaris-oracledbtest-4-lambda/index.js:1:18)",
>         "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)"
>     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you actually did cleanly upgrade node-oracledb.  The error message is something from the [NAN](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) era (pre node-oracledb 4.0) which caused a tight coupling between the node-oracledb binary and Node.js version.  This is why you get messages about the NODE_MODULE_VERSION incopmpatibility. In node-oracledb 4, the implementation changed to use N-API which allows one node-oracledb binary to be used with multiple Node.js versions.